# Winforms UnauthorizedAccessException C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

im trying upload & download file from google drive via c#. Upload process working great but when im download a file im get this error.I search on google and stackoverflow but i cant pass this error.

```
string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    string filePath = desktop + @"\Derslerim\"+textBox2.Text;
    Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
```

and

```
 using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath,FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write))
     {
         fileStream.Write(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, memoryStream.GetBuffer().Length);
     }
```

that code blocks is my create directory and create file areas. Please help me!

Comment: Check if the user that execute the program has full control on the destination folder and this is not marked as read-only on its properties. You can try to execute the program as admin too.

Comment: You'll have to make up your mind, is `filepath` a directory or a file?  Right now it is a directory and you try to create a file with the same name.  That can't work, a file cannot overwrite a directory.